# Can't set device specific constraint on certain xibs

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

In most of my xib's I am able to create constraints based on the dimension of my device.
[image]

[image]

But for some xibs the '+' button is simply not there..

Why is this happening? Is there any workaround to make the plus button appear other than creating a new xib?

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do was to enable the 'Size Classes' property on Files Inspector. Enabling this property will make the xib incompatible for Xcode5 or under.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Be warned,when using size classes the xib files with ~iphone and ~ipad wont work. Make sure you only have 1 xib file for one particular view controller.